# Stop never ending backup in SQL Server 2012 Express

Tags: shrink, sql-server-2012

Our production database log file has grown to consume all disk space on our server.

I know it's bad practice but I want to be able to shrink it in order to restore the service as soon as possible.

Still, when I go and launch my `SHRINKFILE` command,I get this error :

> Msg 3023, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   Backup, file manipulation operations (such as ALTER DATABASE ADD FILE) and encryption changes on
>   a database must be serialized. Reissue the statement after the current
>   backup or file manipulation operation is completed.

It seems to me that the backup will never end. Is there a way to stop it manually ?

(I tried the SQL Server Agent thing, as told in the MSDN documentation, but it is not present in my SQL Server Express)

Comment: You cannot run shrink operation while backup is going on. What do u mean when u say backup is never ending what is wait type , is it blocked

Comment: @Floum: Is this still a issue. Can you update about current situation of problem

Comment: After this problem is resolved, read this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/29829/47920

Answer (score -1):

Restarting SQL Service will kill backup process and then you can shrink. Below query will show you spid of backup process, if any running on server.

```
SELECT *
       FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses
       WHERE --dbid = db_id('YourDatabase') AND --if you want to see status for database
       cmd LIKE 'BACKUP DATABASE%'
```

Below query will kill backup process if you don't want to restart SQL service.

```
Declare @SPIDU Varchar(10), @Query Varchar(50);
SELECT top 1 @SPIDU = spid
       FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses
       WHERE --dbid = db_id('YourDatabase') AND --if you want to see status for database
       cmd LIKE 'BACKUP DATABASE%'
Select @Query = 'KILL ' + @SPIDU + ';'
Exec( @Query)
```

Make sure you do clear trans log by taking backup or else you wont be able to reclaim space from trans log file.

Comment: Whats point in asking OP to restart SQL Server services that would be really a bad idea, he might kill the backup operation. Did you looked at error message.

Comment: If you read question, server is out of space and he is not worried about backup because he wants to shrink file as soon as possible by killing backup. I agree with you about looking at error message but he is not DBA and programmer. I hope you will provide some queries for wait and steps for error message to OP.

Comment: Vishal did u anywhere said in ur answer that why he is getting shrink error. Plus there is no point to restart sql server like u suggested. Your answer is incorrect and does not addresse complete point